# Adding a signature even over HTTPS

Tags: security, https, sha

I am creating a webservice that comunicates over HTTPS.

Security is very important for me, as I cannot accept modified data, so I am thinking about adding a message diggest (signature) to check integrity... but is it needed having it over HTTPS?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it fits better for http://security.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HTTPS already has sufficient signing to prevent accidental modifications.

A straight message digest with no secrets provides no protection against deliberate tampering. An active man-in-the-middle attacker could easily replace the digest with their own value, recalculated to match any alterations they made.

For a signature to have value against tampering it must have been created using a secret key on the sender, and the signature must be verifiable on the receiver, which means you must have a way to pre-exchange keys between parties before use.

For the case where the client is a general purpose web browser there is no channel to do that, other than transferring it over HTTPS at which point that interaction is just as vulnerable to man-in-the-middle attacks and you gain nothing. This is a bootstrap problem.

For the case where you have a custom application client you have distributed to your users through a channel more trusted than HTTPS (eg you physically handing them copies of the code), then yes, adding a server-to-client signature based on public key crypto could theoretically provide some value. But rolling your own crypto is prone to implementation errors and best avoided.

What's the attack you're trying to counter here, that HTTPS together with the commercial CA infrastructure doesn't address well enough?

If your concern is that the PKI of commercial CAs is historically prone to occasional fraudulently-issued certificates and state-level spying, then a much simpler way of defending against that would be to run your own private CA for application use, and have your client accept only certs issued by that CA (and not the certificates built into the system like Verisign et al).

Whether through running a CA, or ad hoc signature checking, running your own PKI securely and effectively is a bunch of ongoing overhead. Be sure the public commercial PKI really can't meet your needs before going that route.

Comment: This is provided on a B2B system where the privates keys are previously exchanged within a USB disk.
To be specific it is a desktop app in not too much machines and a central server that exchanges prices from one to the other clients and vice-versa.
I'm afraid of a man-in-the-middle trying to modify those prices...
For this reason I would like to use HTTPS and send a diggest (SHA256) with a private key inside or something like that....
I just want to be sure that I'm not using bombs to kill simple fly.

Comment: A digest computed with a secret key (normally you'd use an HMAC for this) would require the client to have a copy of that key in order to do the same computation. That would need you to either trust all the clients with the same key (allowing them potentially to masquerade as each other, if they got around the other SSL controls), or manage separate keys for each client. I think using SSL, with your own CA as the only trusted one would be more straightforward, and offers you well-understood procedures for key management.